# Generate a location intent to share to other apps from a Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, intents

Normally, the share mechanism in Google Maps Android App shares text (containing an URL pointing to Google Maps website).

There is though an specific location intent in Android, that any app can catch. When I send such intent from other apps, I can embed a location in messaging apps or open that location in different map apps (including Google Maps).

How do I generate such intent from a pinpointed location in Google Maps, **from the user interface**?

For example, I have installed Maps.ME which does accept location intents too. How do I start a location intent with Google Maps and catch it with Maps.ME, to share a given location? I'm also interested in workarounds if no in-app solution is available.

Comment: Generate an hyperlink with desired coordinates as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon).  Sharing this URL, most apps recognise it as URL and touching it raises an intent which the user can opt to use with any supporting app.

Comment: @Narayanan I'm trying to share that location as a _true_ location intent. I'm unsure which app should I use to open the URL so that it gets recognized as location intent. Other apps are able to share a location and that can be opened in various types of map apps, including Google Maps App.

Comment: For example, I have installed Maps.ME which does accept location intents too. How do I start a location intent with Google Maps and catch it with Maps.ME?

Comment: Then in that case Tasker can raise intents. See [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwji-ZrixqrQAhUIuo8KHeTuBKEQFgggMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D2489449&usg=AFQjCNG7qciQdVRwQtPSqxWJjuCHImXQlw&sig2=nOyk7A9iq5RAqii61xoY8A&bvm=bv.138493631,d.c2I), but you have to figure out how the parameters are passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this app may help you to bridge different map apps. [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.donutpond.sharecoordinates)

you open Google Maps and share that location and choose this app. You can then open it using other maps which accepts location intent.

Hope it helps

Comment: It is a pity that apparently the Google Maps interface does not offer this already. This is indeed the best user-friendly solution.

Comment: @AndresR, i think google did it on purpose because they don't want others to use any third party maps.